# How to access Playwright's launch options

Tags: apify

I am new with apify. I followed this guide and had success in everything: https://docs.apify.com/crawling-basics/headless-browser#headless-env-var

But I don't understand what I need to do in order to "access Playwright's launch options" as mentioned in the link below under "Scraper code".

So I don't understand where can I find this: "In the Apify SDK we can do that in the PlaywrightCrawler constructor."

Comment: The documentation you linked too shows an example of using the Apify constructor to configure launch options, using the `launchOptions` object.  What specifically are you having problems understanding; Are you not creating an Apify object in your code?

Answer (score 2):

I'm Ondra and I wrote the guide, so thank you very much for sharing where you found it hard to understand! We really appreciate it.

In the [preceding section](https://docs.apify.com/crawling-basics/headless-browser#playwright-scraper) you built the Playwright scraper and your code looks like this:

```js
// ... previous code
 
const crawler = new Apify.PlaywrightCrawler({
    requestQueue,
    handlePageFunction: async ({ page, request }) => {
        console.log('URL:', request.url);

// ... following code
```

What you need to do now is to go back to the same code and add this:

```js
const crawler = new Apify.PlaywrightCrawler({
    requestQueue,
    launchContext: { // <========== YOU NEED TO ADD THOSE LINES
        launchOptions: { // <==================================
            headless: true, // <===============================
        }, // <================================================
    }, // <====================================================
    handlePageFunction: async ({ page, request }) => {
        // ...
    },
    // ...
});
```

Adding those lines adds the "Playwright launch options" you talk about.

Comment: Thank you Ondra, I think that I understand it now. Also, I watched your 19 minutes video on YouTube yesterday, thank you very much!! In addition, I am not sure but I think that the line "import { writeFileSync } from 'fs';" is missing under "When we complete the code, it looks like this", here: https://docs.apify.com/data-collection-basics/save-to-csv#writing-to-file

Comment: And maybe also this line? "import { parse } from 'json2csv';" Excuse me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Thanks! I fixed the imports and they should be on the website in a couple of minutes. 